# VBA Help - Update Sharepoint File through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to update a sharepoint file using VBA, essentially this is a plan an employee would submit to their manager, and the manager clicks a button to approve it, which should update a tracker that is housed in sharepoint. I have my code below and noted where I am stuck. Hopefully someone can point me to the right direction! Much appreciated.

```vb
Sub Approve_By_Manager()

    Dim EmployeeName As String
    
    EmployeeName = Workbooks("L&D Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
    
    'Go to sharepoint, open L&D tracker as desktop app THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK :(
    'The file name from sharepoint is called L&D Tracker.xlsm 
    Dim rng As Range 
    Set rng = Workbooks("L&D Tracker.xlsm").Worksheets("2021-Q1").Range("B4", "B62") 
    For Each Cell In rng
        If Cell.Value = EmployeeName Then 
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y" 
            Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Y" 
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open the workbook using `Workbooks.Open(URLhere)`, update and then save it as normal:

```vb
Sub Approve_By_Manager()

    Dim EmployeeName As String, wbMain As Workbook, m, rng As Range
    
    'you can use `ThisWorkbook` to refer to the workbook where your code is running
    EmployeeName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
    
    'Go to sharepoint, open L&D tracker as desktop app
    'The file name from sharepoint is called L&D Tracker.xlsm
    Set wbMain = Workbooks.Open("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Departments/DeptName/Trackers/Main%20Tracker.xlsx")
    Set rng = wbMain.Sheets("Data").Range("B4:B62")
    
    'Match() is faster than looping
    m = Application.Match(EmployeeName, rng, 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        'if m is not an error value then we got a match
        With rng.Cells(m)
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y"
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = "Y"
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Employee '" & EmployeeName & "' not found!"
    End If
    
    wbMain.Save
    wbMain.Close
    
End Sub
```

You might have to experiment a bit with the URL - you can use file >> Open in Excel to try out your edits.
Eg I got this from the "copy link" feature in SharePoint

`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/Departments/DeptA/App%20Docs/App1/Content%20with%20Dates.xlsx?d=w76f80cf0301743068965e28fea4a1440&csf=1&web=1&e=MxhUda`

which I edited to

`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Departments/DeptA/App%20Docs/App1/Content%20with%20Dates.xlsx`

Comment: Hi Tim, so in terms of the Sharepoint path, how would I go about getting it in the format you have specified above? This is what I copied directly from the document itself, but it doesn't seem to be working "https://rbioffice.sharepoint.com/:x:/t/GBS-Miscellaneous/EZS6gNkJdxNGscwR4bsCMrgBQ-HfS15MsHz8Bhaq3gsydg?e=FMtXTl"

Comment: See above for URL's